# Why can't my Perl script locate DBD/mysql.pm even though cpan tells me DBD::mysql is installed?

Tags: perl

OS: Mac 10.12.1, mysql 5.7.15

```
perl -e 'print $];'
5.016000
```

Error message:

> `Can't locate DBD/mysql.pm in @INC (you may need to install the DBD::mysql module) (@INC contains: /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.18 /Network/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.18 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2 /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.18 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18 .) at ./testDBConnection.pl line 8.
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./testDBConnection.pl line 8.`

Source Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#use lib '/usr/bin/cpan'; 
use strict; 
use FileHandle; 
use File::Spec; 
use DBI; 
use DBD::mysql;
```

When I run: `cpan DBD::mysql`

```
Reading '/Users/user/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Fri, 18 Nov 2016 19:41:02 GMT
DBD::mysql is up to date (4.039).
```

When I run: `perldoc -lm DBI DBD::mysql`

> `/Users/user/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/lib/site_perl/5.16.0/darwin-2level/DBI.pm`
>
> `/Users/user/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/lib/site_perl/5.16.0/darwin-2level/DBD/mysql.pm`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like you are using perlbrew. Check out https://perlbrew.pl/

Comment: try running your script with perl directly: `perl script.pl`. Also, changing your shebang line to `#!/usr/bin/env perl` may fix it as well

Comment: @stevieb The problem is that the OP is telling the shell to use `/usr/bin/perl` to execute the script. The script, the shell, and the environment are all under the OP's control. There is no need for workarounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your shebang line refers to `/usr/bin/perl`. That is the interpreter that will be used to execute your script.

`/usr/bin/perl` is the `perl` that comes with your system. You did the right thing by not messing with the modules that came with it and instead installing your own. Now, you should tell your script to use it.

It looks like the correct `perl` is already in your path. Use `which perl` to see the full path to it.

As a side note, there is really no reason for the

```
use DBD::mysql;
```

line. `DBI` will chose which driver to load based on your connection string.

For more on [shebang lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2429515/100754), see [my answer on a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2429515/100754).

[Make links to per-version tools](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2010/03/make-links-to-per-version-tools/) by brian d foy may help. I personally find tools such as `perlbrew` to be more a hindrance than help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've answered your own question. `perldoc` tells you that DBI:mysql is installed in `/Users/user/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/lib/site_perl/5.16.0/darwin-2level/DBD/mysql.pm`, and perl tells you that `INC` does not contain that path.

The simplest solution to start is to either run `perl -I <path above>` or `use lib <path above>;`. I'm sure there's a better solution, but this is enough to get you started solving your own problem.

Comment: Thanks Mort for the tips.